# Getting data from a list on a specific line in a file (python)

Tags: python, list, file, select

I've got a very large file that has a format like this:

> 1. [['1', '2', '3', '4']['11', '12', '13', '14']]
> 2. [['5', '6', '7', '8']['55', '66', '77', '88']]

*(numbers indicate line number)*

The lists on each line are very long, unlike this example.

Now if it was only 1 list I could for example obtain the '11' value with:

```
itemdatatxt = open("tempoutput", "r")
itemdata = eval(itemdatatxt.read())
print itemdata[1][0]
```

However because the file contains a new list on each line I cannot see how I can for example obtain the '55' value.

I thought `itemdatatxt.readline(1)` would select the second line of the file but after reading about the .readline I understand that this would result in the 2nd symbol on the first line.

Can anyone explain to me how to do this? (preferably I wouldn't want to change the 'tempoutput' datafile format)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the whole file to a dictionary where the key is the line number and the value is the content (the two lists). This way you can easily get any value you want by selecting first the line number, then the list and then the index.

*data.txt*

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['11', '12', '13', '14']]
[['5', '6', '7', '8'], ['55', '66', '77', '88']]
[['5', '6', '3', '8'], ['155', '66', '277', '88']]
```

*code*

```
import ast

data = {}
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
  for indx, ln in enumerate(f):
    data[indx] = ast.literal_eval(ln.strip())

print data[1][1][0] #55
print data[1][1][3] #88
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I like it! Will start testing this and let you know!

Comment: Works good. Takes quite some time to load due to the size of the file but fine :) ty.

Comment: Why a dictionary? If the keys are just going to be sequentially ordered numerals wouldn't be more space and time efficient just to use a list?

Comment: @TylerHou It would. I only suggested a full working solution. Just because you have a better implementation doesn't mean that you have to down vote mine.

Comment: I'm was not trying to make a personal attack on you, I'm just said that an array would be better, thus improving the answer for the asker and future askers, as your answer is more visible because it is accepted. I asked to check whether you had some reason that I did not consider for using a dictionary. I'm sorry that I tried to improve your answer, and I won't and I hope others won't try to in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import ast
with open("tempoutput", "r") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i == 1:
            itemdata = ast.literal_eval(line)
            print itemdata[1][0]
            break
```

`enumerate(f)` returns:

```
0, <<first line>>
1, <<second line>>
...
```

So when `i` becomes 1, we've reached second line and we output 55. We also break the loop since we don't care about reading the rest of the lines.

I used `ast.literal_eval` because it's a safer form of eval.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do here but this leads to a ValueError:malformed string.

Comment: You can't eval [['1', '2', '3', '4']['11', '12', '13', '14']] because there isn't a comma between the two arrays. The same with literal_eval. Are commas forgotten or missing by design?

Comment: Yes how silly of me. Forgot those comma's in the example. However I'm not in the clear yet. Seems to get an SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I cannot see what is wrong. 'line 7, in <module>
    itemdata = eval(line)
  File "<string>", line 1
    [['5', '6', ‘7’, ‘8’], [’55', '66', '77', '88']]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

Comment: sorry wrong error message: ''Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xx", line 7, in <module>
    itemdata = ast.literal_eval(line)
  File "xx", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "xx", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    [['5', '6', ‘7’, ‘8’], [’55', '66', '77', '88']]
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax''

Answer (score 0):

`readline()` reads until the next line break. If you call it a second time it will read from where it stopped to the linebreak after that. Thus, you could have a loop:

```
lines = []
with open('filepath', 'r') as f:
    lines.append(eval(f.readline()))
print lines # [[['1', '2', '3', '4'],['11', '12', '13', '14']],
            #  [['5', '6', '7', '8'],['55', '66', '77', '88']]]
```

Or you could read the entire file and split by linebreak:

```
lines = open('filepath', 'r').read().split('\n');
```

Alternatively if you want to read a specific line you can use the linecache module:

```
import linecache

line = linecache.getline('filepath', 2) # 2 is the second line of the file
```